# Assistance with discord.AuditLogAction

Tags: python, logging

I've read discord.py docs, and I haven't found anything related to how to use discord.AuditLogAction()

The thing is, I want everything getting logged by the bot in a specific channel

Like, channel_create, member_prune, webhook_create, and so on.

Since I am too new to discord.py, I cant provide code. Sorry about that

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, `discord.AuditLogAction` represents a type of action being done for a `AuditLogEntry`, which you can retrieve via `Guild.audit_logs()`

[Guild.audit_logs()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20auditlogaction#discord.Guild.audit_logs) has a few examples on it's usage, and should be exactly what you're looking for.

I don't know if sending messages to a specific channel was another question you had, but if so, the [FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) has a little section on how to do [that](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel).